# PHP color table from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, colors

i am having some problems with my  `echo '<tr style="background-color: . $color . '">';` it keeps giving me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'background' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php line 146` and i am pretty new to php so i have no clue what i can do.

My purpes with this code is to get some information from a colum in mysql database and then show it as a table in a website(that i have allready fixed, but i need the colors to work) and then it is going to color some of the table rows after some of their value in the database.

P.S: This is not my whole code.

hope someone can help, Thanks.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


if ( ($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] != "JA") && ($row['Delt'] != "NEI") ) {
    $red ='#ff0000';    
}
else {
    $red = false;
}

if ( (($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] != "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] != "JA")) || (($row['Flyttet'] == "JA") && ($row['Slettet'] != "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] != "JA"))  ) {
    $gul ='#FFFF00';    
}
else {
    $gul = false;
}

if ( ($row['Flyttet'] == "JA") && ($row['Slettet'] != "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] != "NEI") ) {
    $blue ='#1E90FF';    
}
else {
    $blue = false;
}

if ( ($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] != "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] != "JA") ) {
    $green ='#3CB371';    
}
else {
    $green = false;
}


$color = ";
if(!$red && !$gul && !$blue) $color = $green;
if(!$red && !$gul && !$green) $color = $blue;
if(!$red && !$green && !$blue) $color = $gul;
if(!$green && !$gul && !$blue) $color = $red;

    //Første kolone som skal vises
    echo '<tr style="background-color: . $color . '">';
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['ID']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Vsite']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Registrar']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Eier']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['NS']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['A']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['MX']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Flyttet']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Slettet']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Delt']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Behkd']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Varenr']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Server']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Sistoppdatert']) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    }
```

Comment: You need $color = ""; AND echo '<tr style="background-color: '. $color . '">';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: the comment of @KostasMitsarakis will solve you problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using something like this

```
$color = '';

if ( ($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "JA") && ($row['Delt'] == "NEI") ) $color ='#ff0000';
if ( (($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "JA"))|| (($row['Flyttet'] == "JA") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "JA")) ) $color ='#FFFF00';
if ( ($row['Flyttet'] == "JA") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "NEI") ) $color ='#1E90FF';
if ( (($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "JA")) || (($row['Flyttet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Slettet'] == "NEI") && ($row['Delt'] == "NEI")) ) $color ='#3CB371';
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize your variable `color` wrong.
It must be `$color = "";`.

```
$color = "";
    if(!$red && !$gul && !$blue) $color = $green;
    if(!$red && !$gul && !$green) $color = $blue;
    if(!$red && !$green && !$blue) $color = $gul;
    if(!$green && !$gul && !$blue) $color = $red;

    //Første kolone som skal vises
    echo '<tr style="background-color:' . $color . '">';
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['ID']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Vsite']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Registrar']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Eier']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['NS']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['A']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['MX']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Flyttet']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Slettet']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Delt']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Behkd']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Varenr']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Server']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['Sistoppdatert']) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One single quote was missing. It should be like this:

```
echo '<tr style="background-color:' . $color . '">';
```

Answer (score -1):

Your background-color needs double quotes:

```
echo '<tr style="background-color:"' . $color . '"">';
```

Comment: this is wrong, because the tr would then look in html like this `<tr style="background-color:"#ff0000"">`